# Page Object - separating a method that does something from a method that reports if it's done

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, page-object-gem

I have a page-object class with a bunch of methods that do a particular thing. One method, let's call it log_in_with does something like this:

```
def log_in_with(user, pass)
  # does some stuff here
end
```

However, this particular method won't return anything. So in order for me to know whether the user has successfully logged-in, I need to either:

a) Embed this functionality into the existing method, and prob. rename it to log_in_with_and_successful? or make a separate method def login_successful?(user, pass) which is going to call log_in_with and report if the log-in was successful. However it won't be clear what exactly is going on behind the hood, if I call login_successful? from some other class, it isn't clear that this method is BOTH doing the log-in as well as reporting if it's successful.

I'm encountering this method that does something vs. method that reports if it's being done successfully problem all over again. Isn't some design pattern/best practice for solving something like this?

Comment: Why does this method return nothing? Best practice would be to return user if signin is successful and nil if not. Or event better: return instance of User when is successful and User::Guest when null (using e.g. Null Object pattern) with https://github.com/avdi/naught as a help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's good practice to explicitly do one thing with one method. So, do use both `log_in_with(user, password)` and `login_successful?` but do NOT call the former from the latter. Showing both calls in the test itself allows me to easily follow a test's logic and decipher any failure messages, whereas a single `login_successful?` call is confusing and forces me to dive into the class code.

```
describe "logging in" do
  page.log_in_with('username', 'password')
  expect(page.login_successful?).to be_true
end
```